# Is it possible to strengthen forms authentication in ASP.NET with certificates?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

My ASP.NET Internet application uses Forms authentication. There is a limited number of users that will sign up to use application. I don't want to use Windows authentication because it will require me to create Windows accounts for all of them (a few thousand). Is it possible that users must provide a certificate in addition to a username and password?  If so, how can I do that?

Comment: Can you install a certificate on your client's machines ?

Comment: Sure it's possible.  By what are your concerns with forms auth at the moment?

Comment: Yes I can. I want users to use application only in one location (their office). Certificate would authenticate location, username and password would authenticate certain user.

Comment: You could, instead of worrying about Certificate, authenticate location based on IP address.  Most offices have a static IP.  If the IP changes, this will need to be reconfigured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With IIS, it is possible to map a client certificate to a service account that many users can share.

[See here for how to generate and install the client certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302412.aspx)

[See here for how to setup the mapping](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313070)

Once this is complete you will need to install the client certificate on each end users' machine.  This may prove more difficult than creating an account for each user.